# Short story with retired selfdriving cars

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking to identify a short story involving self driving cars. The thrust of the story is a man sets up a sanctuary/farm for retired selfdriving cars. There is a dispute with someone mistreating the cars. I remember a reference to crocodile (alligator?) clips being used in repairs or modifications and this was considered cruel.

Published sometime before the 70s; the style suggests 40s.

Comment: There was a later one published in _Omni_ but I've forgotten the title.

Answer (score 19):

This sounds like *[Sally](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally_(short_story))* by Isaac Asimov.

> The story takes place in 2057. Fifty-one old cars have been retired to a farm run by Jake, where they can be properly cared for.
>
> Raymond Gellhorn, an unscrupulous businessman, tries to steal some of the cars in order to 'recycle' the brains. He forces Jake at gunpoint to board a bus he has poorly wired up to control the vehicle, trying to get away from the farm with Jake as a hostage.

Comment: Agreed. This one is an interesting one because it was an early Asimov story which he later said he regretted a bit because it played into the "robots rise up against humanity" plotline that he disliked so much in the media, part of the reason he came up with his three laws.